# Do I need to use 2 conductor cable for lighting outlets?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I've recently had a metal garage put in. I had an electrician friend run power from the house to the garage, he installed an electrical box with 50 amps, and 1 receptacle outlet. (I just wanted some electric before winter hit us).

The panel has a 15amp breaker in it right now. But I am planning to put a 50amp before I start all the wiring.

I plan to run the wire myself and hook up the all the outlets with 12/2 wire. I'm going to put outlets on my ceiling beams and have plug in LED work lights (6 outlets, 6 Lights). I want these to work off of a switch I'm going to install.

Do I need to run 12/3 wire to all the outlets, or do I just run 12/3 from the switch to one outlet and from that outlet run 12/2 to the others to connect them all

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: FYI, you could've updated the closed one and it would've been reopened. I've removed all the references to that since they're not helpful here.

Comment: Also, don't you mean "3-conductor cable"?

Comment: Yeah, this should have been an edit to the original question, not a new one. I will, once again, ask _why_ do you think you need to run 12/3? Are you planning a MWBC? Do you think the /3 means that it's Hot, Neutral and Ground?

Comment: I'm going to guess that the feeder cable into that box isn't legal. It's well below 6' and isn't in conduit to protect it. Though, I suppose that since it's in the "stud bay", that probably counts as protection.

Comment: Are you talking about putting a 50A breaker in where that single 15A breaker is now?

Comment: Also, when you say 3-conductor cable, that's really 4 wires - 2 hot, 1 neutral, and the bare ground.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question doesn't have any more detail or info than the original question did. There are a dozen questions in the comments on that one that weren't answered, and we're getting the _exact same_ questions on this one. Unless the OP answers these questions on one or the other post, we still can't give answers.

Comment: What are you running off of the 50A breaker? Does it require a neutral or just 2 hots?

Comment: This installation seems very confused.  On one hand, it uses cable which MUST be behind drywall.  On the other hand, the panel and receptacle don't appear to be offset to allow the thickness of drywall. You can get extensions for receptacles but not panels.  So something must be re-done - add drywall or convert to conduit.  Also, the subpanel feeder appears to have only 3 wires, and a subpanel needs 4.

Answer (score 0):

Size/gauge of wire depends on the breaker it is on.

15 amp breaker can use 14 gauge or bigger.

A 20 amp breaker must at minimum have 12 gauge wire, cannot use 14 gauge wire on a 20 amp breaker.

Leds can be on 15 amp breaker and still give you 14 amps of power left over.

If planning to plug in heavy power tools/heaters to those outlets, a 20 amp with 12 gauge wire is a good idea.  Just the LEDs 15 amp/14 gauge is more than enough and usually cheaper and easy to work.

Depending on the circuit path/route 14/2 or 12/2 should be all you need.  Power to switch then switch power to all the outlet/lights.

Only need 14/3 or 12/3 if you want something more fancy, like half switch outlet and half power outlets.

/2 or /3 cables are the amount of conductors plus ground(ground not counted).